# Hadoop log files cannot be found

Tags: hadoop, logging

I have configured hadoop-2.7.2 in windows. I couldn't find any logs in %HADOOP_HOME%\logs directory for hdfs and yarn.

In Hadoop-2.5.2, there will be two log files hadoop.log and yarn.log. But in new hadoop version, the log files are not generated it seems.

How to enable these logs again to debug the services.

Thanks,
Kumar

Answer (score 0):

For *hadoop.log* and *yarn.log* you need to enable this mean.

open %HADOOP_HOME%\etc\hadoop\log4j.properties

Check following properties

```
hadoop.root.logger=INFO,console
hadoop.log.file=hadoop.log
hadoop.log.maxfilesize=200MB
hadoop.log.maxbackupindex=5
log4j.appender.RFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RFA.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.log.file}
```

And set `set YARN_ROOT_LOGGER=INFO,RFA,console` and `set HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=INFO,RFA,console` at *hadoop-env.cmd* and *yarn-env.cmd* respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the response. These properties are already enabled. But still, logs are not saved in file.

Comment: Make sure you referred log4j jars with hadoop-classpath.

Comment: Yes, i have log4j jar in my classpath.

Comment: Thanks Kaveen, I thought to do this. Now it working fine.